# How to bind listview item binding to Viewmodel of the page?

Tags: c#, listview, xamarin, xamarin.forms, binding

I want to bind items in `ListView` to a property in ViewModel instead of ItemsSource but after trying `Binding Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage} Path=ViewModel.TimerValue` it is not working. I am doing something wrong. Not able to identify it

I tried setting :

```xml
Text="{Binding Path=TimerValue, TargetNullValue='00:00', FallbackValue='00:00', StringFormat='{0:mm\\:ss}', Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}"
```

ViewModel does implement INotifyPropertyChanged and raises PropertyChanged event

Page header - referernce

```
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:d="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms/design"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             x:Class="App3.Views.MyPage"
             x:Name="ThisPage">
```

```
<ListView x:Name="listView" ItemsSource={Binding Items}>
                <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <ViewCell>
                            <Label Text="{Binding Path=TimerValue, TargetNullValue='00:00', FallbackValue='00:00', StringFormat='{0:mm\\:ss}', Source={x:Reference Name=ThisPage}}" />
                        </ViewCell>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListView.ItemTemplate>
            </ListView>
```

Code behind

```
 private MyViewModel ViewModel;
 public MyPage () {
     InitializeComponent ();
     ViewModel = new MyViewModel ();
     this.BindingContext = ViewModel;
 }
```

Comment: you want every item in your list to display the same value?

Comment: where/how are you setting the binding context for the xaml?

Comment: @Jason Yes. And I keep changing it based on some events

Comment: @haldo sorry,missed that statement in here.      `this.BindingContext = ViewModel;`

Comment: If I remember correctly the property needs to be public instead of private. Have you tried making `private MyViewModel ViewModel` public instead of private?

Comment: @Knoop ,no. Let me try that.

Comment: it needs to be a **public property**

Comment: Should it be `<Label Text="{Binding Path=ViewModel.TimerValue, TargetNullValue='00:00', FallbackValue='00:00', StringFormat='{0:mm\\:ss}', Source={x:Reference MyPage}}"
        BindingContext="{x:Reference MyPage.ViewModel}"/>`

Comment: I get error, Binding property ViewModel not found  in `App3.Views.MyPage` . Trying `<Label Text="{Binding TimerValue, TargetNullValue='00:00', FallbackValue='00:00', StringFormat='{0:mm\\:ss}'}"
        BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyPage}, Path=BindingContext}"` now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I solved it as below

```
<Label Text="{Binding TimerValue, TargetNullValue='00:00', FallbackValue='00:00', StringFormat='{0:mm\\:ss}'}"
        BindingContext="{Binding Source={x:Reference MyPage}, Path=BindingContext}">
```

Reason Binding was wrong , `BindingContext` has to be `BindableObject`.  `BindingContext` is bindable object which in turn references to `ViewModel` object, and `Label.Text` has to be `BindableProperty` of the bindable object . 
When I referenced `Text={Binding ViewModel.TimerValue` it was trying to find bindable property in `Mypage` however `ViewModel` is just a public property not Bindable object `BindingContext = ViewModel` casts it to Bindable object , hence I had to use that way for Source and Text just calls path of that referenced bindingcontext

Thanks for all the suggestions! Really appreciate this community's prompt responsiveness!

Answer (score 1):

Late answer but might help someone.
In case you are writing layout in code behind. You can bind the context to source viewmodel context in this fashion. I am binding a button to a command inside viewmodel.

```
btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandProperty, new Binding("BindingContext.YourCommand", source: YourListView));
btn.SetBinding(Button.CommandParameterProperty, ".");
```

Answer (score -2):

Two Steps..

1. Give a reference name to your parent View with `x:Name="viewName"` (the view which is bound to the ViewModel)
2. Do the binding as:
   `"{Binding BindingContext.MenuTapCommand, Source={x:Reference viewName}}"`

This works.

Comment: Someone care to explain why this is getting downvoted?

Comment: Maybe because it is duplicated and does not add value? @Abhijith C R